# Sudden jumps in accuracy with logistic regression and bag of words : "glm.fit: algorithm did not converge"

Tags: nlp, r, linear-regression, logistic-regression, glm

I work on a bag of words, on the Toxic Comments Classifications challenge. The challenge is closed but the dataset is very nice to learn.

I use R, tf-idf, tm, and logistic regression.

I have a strange pattern in the accuracy results, linked with the error: "glm.fit: algorithm did not converge". It tired the solution proposed in other answers and multiplied maxit by 4, but it did not help.

#### Glimpse of the functions used

##### sub-sampling

Original distribution is 200K non-toxic (0) and 20K toxic (1)

```
set.seed(42)

df_toxic = df[df$toxic == 1,]
df_ok = df[df$toxic == 0,]

df_ok_sampled = df_ok[sample(nrow(df_ok), nrow(df_toxic)), ]

df_sub = bind_rows(df_ok_sampled,df_toxic)
```

##### Bag of words creation

```
# Words 

control_list_words = list(
    tokenize = words,
    language="en",
    bounds = list(global = c(100, Inf)),
    weighting = weightTfIdf,
    tolower = TRUE,
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    removeNumbers = TRUE,
    stopwords = TRUE,
    stemming = TRUE
)

dtm_words = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control=control_list_words) 
  
# nGrams

control_list_ngrams = list(
    tokenize = nGramsTokenizer,
    language="en",
    bounds = list(global = c(1000, Inf)),
    weighting = weightTfIdf,
    tolower = TRUE,
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    removeNumbers = TRUE,
    # We don't remove stop-words for nGrams as structure like "are a" or "such a" are meaningful for toxic comments
    stopwords = FALSE,
    stemming = TRUE
)
  
dtm_ngrams = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control=control_list_ngrams)

# Merge the two
X = cbind(m_words,m_ngrams)
```

##### Remove correlations

```
highlyCor = findCorrelation(cor(bow), cutoff = cutoff, exact = TRUE)

pruned_bow = bow[,-as.vector(highlyCor)]
```

##### Logistic regression

```
f <- glm(df_toxic ~ ., data=df_train, maxit = 100, family = 'binomial')
```

#### Correlation cutoff vs accuracy

[image: GLM accuracy according to features pruning by correlation detection.]

#### Allure of the confusion matrix

In the high dimensions yet low accuracy intervals: unbalanced

```
           Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 2530 3253
         1  243 5598
```

In the high accuracy intervals: balanced

```
           Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 4883  900
         1  641 5200
```

In the low dimensions and low accuracy intervals: unbalanced in the other way

```
           Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 5272  511
         1 3239 2602
```

#### ???

Do you know what exactly is this "glm.fit: algorithm did not converge" and why raising maxit to 100 did not help?

Thanks

Comment: I guess your data is high dimensional (many columns relative to rows)? I would try to use Lasso/Ridge to shrink estimated coefficients (i.e. the impact of columns which are not powerful to predict the outcome)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes of course! As you can see on the graph, reducing the dimensionality with very small correlation cutoff like 0.3 also works and probably does not have a very high impact of performances. It is not that I'm stuck, it is that I would like to understand. ;-)

Comment: "non convergence" may be due to collinearity in the explanatory variables (very likely with text data). You may also have variables (words or n-grams) which predict some outcome very well. Dominant coefficients can cause problems in maximizing the likelihood, which is a good argument in favor of using regularization (Lasso/Ridge)

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks a lot for the details.

Comment: Maybe have a look here... https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/convergence-of-maximum-likelihood-estimators/